# Automate static html deployment using teamcity and octpous

Tags: html, iis, teamcity, octopus-deploy

Can I use teamcity and octopus for automating Static HTML website deployment.
Currently to deploy Static HTML pages we need to use .NET application.

Thanks,
Prasanna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by packaging the website in a NuGet package and deploying via Octopus. You can use the built-in IIS deployment steps in Octopus or write a custom Powershell deploy.ps1 script if necessary.